# How to put an acess and use a dynamic array within a dynamic array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, struct, dynamic-arrays

I'm trying to use a structure in my c++ project but I've run into a bit of a problem. In my project I create a create a dynamic array after asking the user how many people that have done sales and how many days they worked. After that the program goes through a for loop to in put the data. Here the user is asked to enter names of the people and it then asks the number of units pre day until the a second for loop reaches the max number of days that the user inputted therein lies my problem. I tried using a two dimensional dynamic array put the program kept crashing so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
struct emp{
     string names;
     int *untsold;


}; 



int main(){
     int people;
     int days;
     emp *workers;
     cout<<"How many workers are we looking at?"<<endl;
     cin>>people;
     cout<<"How many days are we looking at?"<<endl;
     cin>>days
     workers = new emp[people,days];
     for(int index=0;index<people;index++){
          cin.ignore();
          cout<<"Enter the name of worker number "<<index+1<<"."<<endl;
          getline(cin,emp[index,0].names);
          for(int index2=0;index2<days;index++){
              cout<<"Now enter the number of units sold on day "<<index2+1<<endl;
              cin>>*workers[index,index2].untsold;
          }

     }



}
```

The rest of the program is just displaying the information in a table then delete the dynamic array. The program seems crash right after I enter in something for the *workers[index,index2].untsold variable. Is it possible to put an array of variables within a dynamic array or should I try something else. Please mind that my teacher wants me to use both structure variables and dynamic arrays also note that I'm a beginner.

Comment: Umm...this doesn't look like it'd even compile.  `workers[index,index2]`?  `new emp[people,days]`?  This isn't C++.

Comment: _workers = new emp[people,days];_ I am not able to understand this..

Comment: by "crashing", presumably you mean "I get compilation errors"?

Comment: There's some semicolons missing in there, too. This will get a lot of compilation errors.

Comment: Voting to close as unreproducible.  This code won't even compile, let alone run, let alone exhibit the behavior mentioned.

Comment: Well, this could be `workers = new emp[ operator,(index,index2) ]` assuming that you could call the default `operator,` as a free function (which you cannot). That is, it *can* compile; if not do the expected.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Ah...hadn't thought about that.  I guess that would compile.  There are other syntax issues too, though.

Comment: By crashing I mean it works up until I enter in the input something in to the untsold variable.

Answer (score 2):

Use `std::vector` for dynamic size arrays.

To implement a matrix, the simplest and most efficient is to use a single `vector` to hold all items, then compute index in the single vector from specified (x, y) location in matrix.

If you want operator notation for (x, y) indexing, use `operator()` (which can take any number of arguments), not `operator[]` (which can take only one argument). It's technically *possible* to use multiple applications of square brackets indexing, but it gets complicated and advanced fast, depending on proxy objects to represent partial indexing – so do use either a named operation, or `operator()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
new emp[people,days]
```

does not allocate a two dimensional array - the *comma operator* evalutes the left hand side, throws away the result, then returns the value of the right hand side.
The code is equivalent to

```
new emp[days]
```

And since you never allocate the `untsold` meber of any struct,

```
*workers[index,index2].untsold;
```

which is equivalent to

```
*workers[index2].untsold
```

dereferences an uninitialized pointer, which is undefined.

It is better to use `std::vector`, but if you're trying to learn about arrays, you should re-read that part of your fine C++ book.